# Angular AgmMaps: can't use PolylineManager, with error: "[Front for longstractor/server0.conn0.child1/longstractor372]"

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to draw a polyline (some lines that follow each other, for describing a bicycle route, per example) in my map. The map currently has some entities that are loaded via template, with the typical *nFor.

As the AGM library states, there are many injectables that can draw things in the map. One of those injetables is `PolylineManager`, which is perfect for my use case. As it's supposed to be an injectable that is present in the `@agm/core` module (which is properly imported in my module and working), I just injected it in my map component's constructor, just like:

```
 private agmPolyManager: PolylineManager
```

Well, thing is, that when I do this, even before using it anywhere in the app, the view crashes when I try to enter, and I get the following, totally non-sense error:

> Error: "[Front for longstractor/server0.conn0.child1/longstractor372]"

I haven't found this error anywhere in the web. Tried to update the package and so, but it didn't give any results...

Comment: I did get an exception when I added it to my project. I added both PolylineManager and GoogleMapsAPIWrapper to the providers in my app.module.ts and was able to get past the exception. I did not try to use it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this error is related but I had a similar error while trying to redirect to another route.

```
ERROR Error: "[Front for longstractor/server0.conn8.child1/longstractor59654]"
```

The error didn't say anything about what was wrong, so I enabled the tracing on my routing module and the logs showed me what was the error.

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
]
```